# Bind control property from the inner control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates, winrt-xaml

I have a control that contains another control. InnerControl contains some property like ButtonVisibility. The simplified InnerControl code sample is below

```
public class InnerControl : ControlBase
{
    //...
    public Visibility ButtonVisibility
    {
        get { return (Visibility)GetValue(ButtonVisibility); }
        set { SetValue(ButtonVisibility, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonVisibility =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ButtonVisibility",
            typeof (Visibility),
            typeof (InnerControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Collapsed));
}
```

This is the code of MainControl which contains InnerControl as a Dependency Property

```
public class MainControl : ControlBase
{
    //...
    public InnerControl MyInner
    {
        get { return (InnerControl) GetValue(MyInnerProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyInnerProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyInnerProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "MyInner",
            typeof (InnerControl),
            typeof (MainControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, OnMyInnerPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnMyInnerPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

I have two different templates for this controls in the Generic.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="local:InnerControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:InnerControl">
                <Grid x:Name="ContainerGrid">
                    <!-- some markup -->
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="local:MainControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MainControl">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">

                    <Button x:Name="MyButton" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ???}"/>

                    <ContentControl x:Name="MyInnerControl" Content="{TemplateBinding MyInner}" />

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This is the way how could I use this controls

```
<controls:MainControl>
    <controls:MainControl.MyInner>
        <controls:InnerControl ButtonVisibility="Visible">
            <!-- some markup -->                
        </controls:InnerControl>
    </controls:MainControl.MyInner>

    <!-- some markup -->
</controls:MainControl>
```

I need to change the state of my `MainControl` after button's click. That's why it is located in `MainControl` template.

So, could any body gives me an advise how to bind `ButtonVisibility` from the `MyInner` to the `MyButton` on `MainControl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind directly to the "ButtonVisibility" property of InnerControl, like this:

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" 
        Visibility="{Binding MyInner.ButtonVisibility, 
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
```

Comment: James, can you help me with another one question? If MyInner is null how can I set Button Visibility to Collapsed automatically? I tried to set up TargetNullValue=Collapsed, but it doesn' work in WinRT

Comment: @PavelGriza instead of null, you could make it have a default value (new PropertyMetadata(<defaultInnerControl>, OnMyInnerPropertyChanged ...

Answer (score 1):

Like @james mentioned, you will have to use RelativeSource to bind to either TemplatedParent or to any Type in the visual tree by specifying type like:

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" Content="MyButton" 
       Visibility="{Binding Path=MyInner.ButtonVisibility, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                           AncestorType={x:Type controls:MainControl}}}"/>
```

Comment: Just noting that x:Type is not supported in winrt-xaml. The OP has not specified what platform he is writing for but I think it would be useful to note.

Answer (score -1):

WPF AttachedProperty helps to change the state of your main control from your inner control.